# LINQ expression could not be translated querying child list properties

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

Doing something that seems really simple using EF, DbContext and CosmosDB.  Trying to get a list of items based on a field in a child list being equal to a parameter.

Source of the predicate to the repository:

```cs
public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<GameResponse>> Handle(GetMyUpcomingGamesQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var test = await _repository.GetAsync(p => p.Players.Any(z=>z.Id == request.ProfileId));

...
```

Source of the repository:

```cs
public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<GameReadModel>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<GameReadModel, bool>> predicate)
{
    return await _context.GameReadModels.AsNoTracking().Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
}
```

Source of read model:

```cs
namespace Common.Domain.ReadModels
{
    public class GameReadModel 
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public VenueReadModel Venue { get; set; } 

        public string Notes { get; set; }

        public DateTimeOffset Begins { get; set; }

        public DateTimeOffset Ends { get; set; }

        public int NumberOfPlayers { get; set; }

        public decimal MinimumRating { get; set; }

        public decimal MaximumRating { get; set; }

        public bool OpenToLobby { get; set; }

        public string GameType { get; set; }

        public ProfileReadModel Host { get; set; } 

        public IReadOnlyCollection<ProfileReadModel> Players { get; set; } = new List<ProfileReadModel>();  
        
        public IReadOnlyCollection<ListItemReadModel> Lists { get; set; } = new List<ListItemReadModel>();

        public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }

        public DateTimeOffset Modified { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(g => EF.Property<IReadOnlyCollection>(g, "Players")
> .AsQueryable()
> .Any(o => o.Id == __request_ProfileId_0))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

If I first query the list using a property value OTHER THAN the child list, it works fine.  To do this in more than one step however would result in a LOT of extraneous fetching.

It feels like the child list is not materialized or available for the subquery in some way.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to make your "Players" collection a traditional "virtual ICollection<ProfileReadModel>"?

Comment: Of course, but could you explain why and what I should be looking for?

Comment: Try to replace `IReadOnlyCollectiion` with mutable collection `ICollection`. Maybe EF Core is sensitive for that.

Comment: ^^ Sorry that made no difference.

Comment: Then try without repository. Something missed here, Code looks good.

Comment: Not a fan of the generic repository pattern, but that looks like it should work if Players is a normal one-to-many relational mapping. It may be a bit of a hassle but you could try a with an SQL Server database. This may be a translation bug/limitation /w CosmosDB, or specific to how that relationship is stored.

Comment: Oh, missed that this is CosmosDB. It's translator very limited for querying.

Comment: >> Then try without repository. Something missed here, Code looks good. 

Requesting this directly from the context (skipping the repository) resulted in the identical error.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: After banging my head on this a while I switched to a specification pattern and the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos library and and getting good results.  The spec pattern creates and expression using Linq and works.  If you want it or want to see it LMK.